# How to nest 2 or more routing levels with parameters in Angular 2 on Dart

Tags: angular, dart

I have an Angular 2 application written in Dart that has multiple nested routes with parameters.

The highest level route has a parameter "category" and works perfectly:

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/', name: 'Empty', component: Empty, useAsDefault: true),
  const Route(path: '/categories/:category/...', name: 'Category', component: Category)
])
class AppComponent { /* Content omitted */ }
```

HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="['Category', {'category': cat['id']}]">{{cat['name']}}</a>
```

Category has a RouteConfig as well which defines a parameter "product":

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/', name: 'Empty', component: Empty, useAsDefault: true),
  const Route(path: '/products/:product', name: 'Product', component: Product)
])
class Category { /* Content omitted */ }
```

When I try to create a link to a product like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['Category/Product', {'category': id, 'product': product['id']}]">{{product['name']}}</a>
```

I get following error:

```
Route generator for 'category' was not included in parameters passed.
```

I also tried `Product` and `./Product` in the link, both of which resulted in following error:

```
Component "AppComponent" has no route named "Product".
```

I have pushed the full source to Github: https://github.com/stijnvanbael/angular2-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Category', {'category': id}, 'Product', {'product': product['id']}]">{{product['name']}}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me one step further. But now the output of the `Category` component is rendered again in the `Category`'s router outlet. Any idea how I can get the `Product` component there?

Comment: Sorry, no idea? Did you add the `/` at the beginning of the route?

Comment: Yes I did. But putting a `/` or no `/` did not make any difference.

Comment: You don't by any chance have added `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` anywhere else than at `bootstrap(AppComponent, [...])`?